# Primefaces layout positioning and sizing

Tags: layout, primefaces

Is it possible in Primefaces 3.5 make the following layouts? 
Thank you.

[image]
-------------------------------------Or--------------------
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create this layout using simple html and css, but if you are asking if there is a specific layout component in Primefaces that could help you with this layout - there is.

The p:layout can help you with that.

This example shows the bottom layout:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutMailbox.jsf

And here are some others:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutHome.jsf